# Adding noise to a signal with a specified SNR

Tags: matlab

I have a cosine signal and some interference consisting of a sine noise signal and a random noise signal. I am trying to add these noise signals to the cosine signal with an SNR of 2 dB. To achieve this I have done the following:

- First, I have added the two noise signals to get a single noise signal;
- then I have used Parseval's theorem to calculate the power of each signal, the cosine signal and the new resultant noise signal;
- then I have edited the noise signal with the required power to achieve this SNR by normalizing it by the square root of its current power and multiplying it by the square root of the required power. The required power is derived from the formula of the SNR as :

  Power of noise = power of the cosine signal / 10^SNR/10;
- Finally, I have checked the new SNR and the result wasn't 2 dB.

Here is my code :

```
fs=250;
n=0:1/fs:4; 
interference=sin(2*pi*(50)*n); % interference signal
random_noise=rand(size(n)); %  random noise signal
noise_signal=interference+random_noise;% determinning the tottal noisy signal that will be added later
signal= cos(2*pi*(50)*n); % Definning signal of interest 
signal_power=sum(abs(signal.^2)) ; %u sing parseval's theorem
current_noisy_signal_power=sum(abs(noise_signal.^2)); % using parseval's theorem
pn=signal_power/(10^(2/10)); % required SNR =2dB
new_noisy_signal=(noise_signal./sqrt(current_noisy_signal_power)).*sqrt(pn); % normalizing the noisy signal to get unity power then multiplying it by the new power to achieve the required SNR
new_noisy_signal_power=sum(abs(new_noisy_signal.^2));
SNR=10*log(signal_power/new_noisy_signal_power)
```

So what is wrong in my code? Why isn't the SNR 2 dB?

Comment: I see a project description and code, but am missing the question part of a *question* and answer site.

Comment: Thank you very much @Adriaan for your reply but unfortunately i can't understand you

Comment: He's asking you to ask a question. All you've done is post code and talk about it. What is the question?

Comment: I bet you get an "unknown variable or function" error, you use `noisy_signal`, but never define it. Please fix your code while you're editing the question into the question.

Comment: Ok sorry for that . I have edited my question

Comment: @CrisLuengo , i have edited the code , it was a typo. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SNR is typically computed using the base-10 logarithm, which matches also with the way you computed 2dB: `(10^(2/10))`. So, use `log10` instead of `log` when computing the SNR:

```
>> SNR = 10*log10(signal_power/new_noisy_signal_power)
SNR =  2.0000
```